# Smarty sub-object referencing

Tags: php, object, reference, smarty

In smarty I'm having to load data from an object using a function ala: $obj->Function1(1) I then want to be able to acces a value that function returns like this: $obj->Function1(1)->name but get this error "unrecognized tag: $cat->getSubCategories(1)->name " is there an easy way of getting this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to assign the result of `Function1()` to a variable. It's not pretty but it should work.

```
{assign var='foobar' value=$cat->getSubCategories(1)}
{$foobar->name}
```